# node.js: Talk to npm from within a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'd like to add a self-updating feature to a globally installed module. Is there a better way of doing it than this?

```js
require("child_process").exec("npm update -g module-name");
```

There's some [documentation](https://github.com/npm/npm#using-npm-programmatically) about installing `npm` as a local dependency. Is this necessary? Is there any sample code on how to execute commands like `update` or `install` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've usually done to use the system copy of npm instead of installing another copy of npm as a local module:

```
function loadNpm(cb) {
  require('child_process').exec('npm', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    var m = /npm@[^ ]+ (.+)\n/i.exec(stdout);
    if (!m)
      return cb(new Error('Unable to find path in npm help message'));
    cb(undefined, require(m[1]));
  });
}


// usage ...
// only need to call `loadNpm()` once
loadNpm(function(err, npm) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // load() is required before using npm API
  npm.load(function(err, npm) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // e.g. npm.search('ssh', true, function(err, results) { console.dir(results); });
  });
});
```

Comment: Pretty clever, thanks. I take it, I'd have to dig through the npm source to find out the parameters to functions like `npm.update`?

Comment: @silverwind The npm API is documented [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/tree/master/doc/api).

Comment: Notices a slight problem with above code: The `.exec("npm")` call results in an `[Error: Command failed: ]`. It still works fine when ignoring the error, thought.

Comment: The behavior probably changed since I first wrote that script a long while back. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your goals, here are a few options:

1) Via exec() as you mention. Don't forget to add an error callback.

2) Using the npm package as you mention.

For example, I wrote a quick script to install the Yeoman package globally which worked well. I didn't see a lot of documentation for this so I started reading the source code in the npm package itself.

```
var npm = require('npm');

npm.load (function (err, npm) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error loading");
        return;
    }

    npm.config.set('global', true);
    npm.commands.install(['yo'], function (err)  {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Installation failed");
        }
    });
});
```

3) Another option is to just have a cron job auto-update packages if that is your goal.

4) You may also be interested in this package https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates

Comment: The goal is to update a running server app on demand. I think I'll go with getting a reference to the global `npm` via mscdex's answer, and then proceed with installing like you did. Also +1 for that global flag, I was wondering on how to set it as `npm.commands` didn't accept it.

Comment: Ended up using `npm.install` which seems superior to `npm.commands.install` as it gives some useful information to the callback.

Comment: Interesting. A couple of other approaches to loading the global npm module:

1) Instead of depending on the npm help and using regular expressions, you can do 'npm ll -g npm --json' and then get the 'path' field in the JSON. 

2) The following *might* be sufficient as well.

var path = require('path');

var npm = require(path.dirname(process.execPath) + '/../lib/node_modules/npm');